# Instance variable & properties in blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, instance-variables

All objects are in the heap, that is obvious, but what about the instance variables?
Do they change the retain count? If yes, can they be directly used and modified in blocks?

I came across a tutorial which says blocks can modify objects that are in the heap. So another question arises: Can we modify a heap object without using 
`__block` before the object type?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  However you can modify an instance variable of an object without using `__block` and `__block` is generally only required to update local variables (i.e. stack based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `__block` qualifier in order to modify instance variables. You were on the right track in thinking about this. If a thing is on the heap, it's persistent. If it is stack based, like a local variable, it does need to be marked with __block if the block modifies it.